# How to putextra arraylist<object> with if statement and show it in other activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

## Activiy 1

```
List<Goods> goodsList = new ArrayList<>();
goodsList = getAllData();
Goods goods = new goods();
intent.putExtra("listbarang", (Serializable) goodsList);
```

function `getAllData()` is my function to show all data in my database, and I show it with RecyclerView by the way.

## Activity 2

```
goodsList = (List<Goods>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listbarang");
```

and there's how I get the ArrayList

all I want is put extra the ArrayList with the specific condition with if statement. For example, I want to show only the goodies who have stock more than 0.

I have succeeded to store the ArrayList. But I want to get specific data for that condition, maybe using looping or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand with your question, I think you probably need to pass the criteria with the list. Something like this:

```
intent.putExtra("listbarang", goodsList);
// Criteria for at least one item in the list
intent.putExtra("criteria", 1);
```

Then process the extra:

```
int criteria;

Intent intent = getIntent();
goodsList = (List<Goods>) intent.getSerializableExtra("listbarang");
criteria = intent.getIntExtra("criteria", 0);

// do something based on criteria
for(Goods good: goodsList) {
  if(good.getStock >= criteria) {
    // process the good.
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer is the great one , but i have problem , i dont want to show the array list who have true criteria , how can i do that ? i working on RecyclerView.

Comment: It is simple, you can create another list based on the criteria then feed it to your RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: can you make example ?

Answer (score 0):

you can implements your Goods class from Parcelable, and use Bundle.putParcelableArrayList to store your list data.

Comment: i was implements my Goods class (which is POJO) to serializable , what the difference  from parcelable and serializable ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for passing arrayList between activities, fragment and storing them in sharedPreferences.

```
Passing arrayList of Object type from One Activity to another activity.

This solution will also used for passing from one fragment to another fragment

or fragment to activity or activity to fragment.

And this also helps to store arrayList of object type in sharedPreferences.

First added this dependency in build.gradle(app) file


compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'


for e.g.:

//first Activity
ArrayList<Goods> list=new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson=new Gson();
String goodList=gson.toJson(list);
Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putString("goods",goodList);
startActivity();


//Second Activity
Gson gson=new Gson();
String goodList=getIntent().getString("goods");
Type type=new TypeToken<ArrayList<Goods>>(){}.getType();
List<Goods> list = new gson.fromJson(goodList,type);
```

I hope this solution will help  you.
Thanks

Comment: but , how to get specific data on the array list ? there is no looping ?